# How can I replace TimThumb with WordPress native image tools?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have recently started work on an existing WordPress site.  The theme on the WordPress install uses TimThumb excessively, and it really is unnecessary.  WordPress native image sizes should be able to handle the functionality required.  However, I am not sure how to replace TimThumb.

There is a `post-thumb.php` in the theme file that generates the thumbnails.  The file is as follows:

```
if (get_option('solostream_default_thumbs') == 'yes') { $defthumb = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/def-thumb.jpg'; } else { $defthumb == 'false'; }

$solostream_img = get_the_image(array(
    'meta_key' => 'thumbnail',
    'size' => 'thumbnail',
    'image_class' => 'thumbnail',
    'default_image' => $defthumb,
    'format' => 'array',
    'image_scan' => true,
    'link_to_post' => false, ));

if ( $solostream_img['url'] && get_option('solostream_show_thumbs') == 'yes' && get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'remove_thumb', true ) != 'Yes' ) { ?> 

    <img class="<?php echo $solostream_img['class']; ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $solostream_img['url']; ?>&amp;w=150&amp;h=150&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

<?php } 

} ?>
```

I just want to replace this entire function with WordPress' built in `the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail')` function.

Is it as simple as replacing

```
src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $solostream_img['url']; ?>&amp;w=150&amp;h=150&amp;zc=1"
```

with something like

```
src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>"
```

Any ideas or a push in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try your idea and see what happens.

Comment: Well, it broke all the images that were using the `post-thumb.php` call, haha.  But, it might have helped me out.  The markup returned was as follows: 

    `<img class="thumbnail" src="<img width="150" height="150" src="path/to/correct/thumb.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" />"  />`

So, I think I should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom thumbnails and use them within your code.

First you have to add theme support, set the thumbnail name, set the size, and set the size

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); // this enable thumbnails and stuffs
add_image_size( 'mini-thumbnail', 60, 60, true );
add_image_size( 'one-more-size', 300, 260, true );
```

You can then use this in your code by calling the following:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_title();
the_post_thumbnail( 'mini-thumnail' );
the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Wordpress has a good reference page for this implementation and functions: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: I updated the link to a more authoritative link from Wordpress that includes examples and links to the functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way, but I have been able to get it working by replacing

```
<img class="<?php echo $solostream_img['class']; ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $solostream_img['url']; ?>&amp;w=150&amp;h=150&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

with

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
```